# python: convert each element to string in a list, without using for loop

Tags: python

for solving above problem I normally use for loop like that:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', 3,32423,5.76, "afef"]
list2 = []
for ele in list1:
  list2.append(str(ele))
```

does python has some build in function for solving that problem?

Comment: use `list comprehensions` eg `[str(i) for i in list1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) like the following:

```py
list1 = ['1', '2', 3, 32423, 5.76, "afef"]
list2 = list(map(str, list1))
```

Comment: for this simple solution even list2=list1 will also work. Correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi What do you mean? `list1` contains numbers like `3`, `32423`, `5.76`, but `list2` contains only strings. `list1 == ['1', '2', 3, 32423, 5.76, 'afef']` while `list2 == ['1', '2', '3', '32423', '5.76', 'afef']`.

Comment: @SwayWu Happy to hear that! You can also accept my answer if you want to :) You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers